# Which JavaScript function is compatible with PHP urldecode function?

Tags: php, javascript

On the server side the PHP code will be using `urldecode()` function to decode, but the JavaScript code is responsible to encode the URL. Which of the following JavaScript function is compatible with the PHP `urldecode()` function:

> - escape()
> - encodeURI()
> - encodeURIComponent()

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `encodeURI` or `encodeURIComponent`. The php manual states:

> Decodes any %## encoding in the given string.

So whatever the encoding function encodes, all `%##` sequences are decoded. So you can use either one of the JavaScript functions to encode it.

#### edit:

(In kind-of response to Gumbo's answer, which he removed?)

php's `urldecode` also decodes `+` signs to spaces (because it implements a different standard). To make sure that no plus signs that are actually intended are decoded on the php side, just use `encodeURIComponent` to be sure. That encodes `+` to `%2B`, which is then again safe from php's `urldecode`.

Comment: [`rawurldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php) does not mangle plus signs, while plain old `urldecode` does.